# How can I replace only the captured elements of a regex?

Tags: php, regex, perl

I'm trying to extract only certain elements of a string using regular expressions and I want to end up with only the captured groups.

For example, I'd like to run something like `(is|a)` on a string like `"This is a test"` and be able to return only `"is is a"`. The only way I can partially do it now is if I find the entire beginning and end of the string but don't capture it:

```
.*?(is|a).*? replaced with $1
```

However, when I do this, only the characters preceding the final found/captured group are eliminated--everything after the last found group remains.

```
is is a test.
```

How can I isolate and replace only the captured strings (so that I end up with `"is is a"`), in both PHP and Perl?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
I see now that it's better to use `m//` rather than `s///`, but how can I apply that to PHP's `preg_match`? In my real regex I have several captured group, resulting in `$1`, `$2`, `$3` etc -- `preg_match` only deals with one captured group, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you want are the matches, the there is no need for the `s///` operator. You should use `m//`. You might want to expand on your explanation a little if the example below does not meet your needs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = 'This is a test';

my @matches = ( $text =~ /(is|a)/g );

print "@matches\n";
__END__

C:\Temp> t.pl
is is a
```

**EDIT:** For PHP, you should use [`preg_match_all`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and specify an array to hold the match results as shown in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace only captures. `s///` always replaces everything included in the match. You need to either capture the additional items and include them in the replacement or use assertions to require things that *aren't* included in the match.

That said, I don't think that's what you're really asking. Is [Sinan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029159/how-can-i-replace-only-the-captured-elements-of-a-regex#1029214) what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

You put everything into captures and then replaces only the ones you want.

```
(.*?)(is|a)(.*?)
```